# Evaluating Globals PageNumber / TotalPages in IIF statement in header

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that breaks on group.  In the header, I show the group name.  Last page of the report is district totals.  After all groups, I can just toss in the DistrictName + " TOTALS", right?

But it's not working.

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber < Globals!TotalPages,
     ReportItems!Xxxxxx.Value, 
     Parameters!District.Value + " TOTALS")
```

**ReportItems.Xxxxxx** shows up fine for every page.

But the last page refuses to spit out **Parameters!District.Value**, which leaves a void and my whole heading shifts to the left.  Even the following doesn't work:

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber < Globals!TotalPages,
     ReportItems!Xxxxxx.Value, "DISTRICT TOTALS")
```

Which leads me to wonder if the Globals are not evaluating as I expect, on the last page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Globals!OverallTotalPages.  It is possible that the Globals!TotalPages is getting reset between groups and impacting your textbox logic.